# how to add form control group dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms, form-control, angular-formbuilder

I am new to angular and I am adding some field using form controls based on my requirements. I need to add a few fields dynamically which contains an array. But I don't know how to show the user that kind of functionality in the UI. Kindly help to achieve that. Here is the sample JSON

```
{
  "city": "hyderabad",
  "comboDesciption": "ioioioyio",
  "label": "combo", 
  "price": 650,
  "productIds": "Mutton Liver,Chicken",
  "qtyIds": "500gm,700gm"
}
```

In the above JSON, I have productIds where I need to pick multiple products for a combo and their respective quantity weights are referred to in the qtyIds. Kindly suggest me how to add my form control group in array to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Here is how you can use reactive forms in your case:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
   city: [null, Validators.required),
   comboDescription: [null, Validators.required),
   label: [null, Validators.required),
   price: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]),
   productsIds: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
   qtyIds: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
 })
}

// create getters to retrieve the form array controls from the parent form group
public get productsIds(): FormArray {
  return this.myForm.get('productsIds') as FormArray;
}

public get qtyIds(): FormArray {
  return this.myForm.get('qtyIds') as FormArray;
}

// create methods for adding and removing productsIds
public addProduct(): void {
  this.productsIds.push(this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]));
}

public removeProduct(index: number): void {
  if(this.productsIds.length < 1) {
   return;
 }

  this.productsIds.removeAt(index);
}

// do the same for the qtyIds
```

In the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  .
  .
  .
  // example for productsIds
  <div formArrayName="productsIds">
    <button (click)="addProducts()">Add Product</button>

    <div *ngFor="let productId of productsIds.controls; index as i">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
      <button (click)="removeProduct(i)">Remove Product</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

Comment: Here I need to add two types of add and removes right one for productId and another for quantity weights. Is there are any other simple way? I can solve that. So that in the UI user won't get confused

Comment: From what I've understood you want arrays for both fields. So yes, you need to handle both cases. Of course, you can create helper methods if you want to not repeat yourself.